# Share a file or web page(html would work too) to a specific person using internet

Tags: web-server, internet, wamp

I know there are lots of methods of sharing now but I want to create a web page and publish it on the web but don't want search engines to find it.I don't even want any custom domain or any domain at all, even an IP address would work.I don't want to pay for anything like web hosting or whatever.

What I would like to do is this:

I would give a url address like 198.67.76.xx.xx:yyyy to someone.(I don't know how this can be achieved).They would open that url using internet and land to a page which I created and wanted them to see. Whoever has this address should be able to access whatever I have shared there. I don't care about file size limits.If they can access only a simple page, my job would be done.

In short, I want to use some kind of primitive technology or primitive system of sharing on internet, if that's what it is.

If it is possible for anyone to assume that specific person as me and me as yourself, you can make a webpage (even a blank one would do) and share it to me by giving me a URL so that I can directly judge if that's what I am looking for. This would be very very great. I'll be grateful. Thank you!

You can use any software you want.

**Edit:**

---

**Progress Update: So far I've created one HTML page (with input form where inputted data is sent to a local server using post method) and one php file (which helps to receive the data from the html page and insert it into a mySQL database.**

What I have done till now:

I installed WAMPserver to get Apache, Mysql PHP etc. all at once. I saved the html file (with `<form action="http://localhost/xyz.php "....</form>`) in a local directory and I created the php file xyz.php (with `...$_POST['input field name in the html']...`) and saved it in the special directory C://wamp64/www/

Now, when I start the WAMPserver (Local server), I can access the php page with the address "http://localhost/xyz.php". Also, whenever I submit a data through the html page, the php page automatically opens and the data gets stored as per the coding in the php file (only when the server is "on", that's a good thing). All this is happening within my own computer and on a local server, not requiring any internet connection.

What I want to do:

I want to share the html page (the web page coded with html, not the file `<html>...</html>`) globally on the internet or to the specific person only (if possible) who can access the page using the internet (the person is far from my place and is not directly connected with my local server, but through internet, I guess).**The inputted data shall still be sent to the mySQL database existing on my local server only,** i.e., the php page and the database created within it should remain secret, though the php page opens as the data is inputted in the html page, that's not a problem since the secrecy with whoever is able to input the data is not needed.

My question: How can I do so using WAMPserver or any other software (you can recommend),  which must be free.

Comment: Also, I don't want to use free subdomain etc. or any third party website publishing sites like google sites, wix etc. I want to do something very basic which might not be as popular as it used to be once.

Comment: look into `onion share`

Comment: @totalynotanoob if I host a website using onion share what will the url look like?

Comment: it will be an .onion site. They generally just have random alpha numeric characters and end with .onion. you can access the site with the [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/de/download/)

Comment: @totalynotanoob With onion share, can i share something to someone who don't have onion share?

Comment: yes but they need `Tor Browser` or a different .onion capable browser

Comment: @totalynotanoob what about webpage? If i create a web page with a url like you said some numbers.onion, can't this be opened in any browser? Besides, could you please name some famous onion capable browsers?

Comment: no .onion sites can not be opened by all browsers as they are onion routed

Comment: @totalynotanoob any other software recommendation? Or like I said any primitive method of hosting webpages on the internet?

Comment: no, I don't know much about hosting websites. But if you just want to get a website up you really only need `apache` or `nginx`

Comment: @totalynotanoob Thank you very much for your replies. I'll definitely check apache and nginx.Thanks again!

Comment: Correction in bounty details: that -> then* (..then I'm ready to use that software)

Comment: Why not just encrypt it & email it?

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica because I don't know the email of that specific person. Besides I would like to know more about the encryption thing you mentioned.

Comment: Just curious  - how will you communicate the http address of your web page to the other person?

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica Physically maybe. That's a secret. For hosting a website, are AWS and azure free? What's the difference between them and Apache or nginx, I was previously recommended.

Comment: Lolx! You don't trust Google, but will let Amzon or Microsoft host your website? Apache is a free and ***open source*** (read "peer reviewed, so should contain no bad stuph" web server, which you could run in your own PC. I don't know nginx, but it looks closed source. Btw, since you are so paranoid, remember that two people can keep a secret - if one of them is dead :-)

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica I couldn't stop laughing (at me ofcourse and because what I want to achieve makes me look paranoid and it appears as if security is what I care about most here) This is because I was telling you things (different from reality) that can serve the same purpose. Now I think I've to make it clear. I don't have any problem with third party website hosting services (even if they could clearly see my page). I don't even have any problem with sharing it openly on the internet, no problem with search engines. I can share the same page with you too considering the fact that ..

Comment: ...you won't be able to understand the context you'll see in the page. It will be mostly blank except an input field! I just mentioned that I don't want to share it on internet because what I wanted was far less demanding than that, which is just to share with a specific person. And I thought publishing on internet may require me to pay some money!

Comment: @JoshZhang I've edited my question. Please reply if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You could use **[Mongoose Web Server](https://mongoose.ws/)**, it's a very lightweight and simple application to host a web page.

Installing and using Mongoose is actually the easy part. The hard part is actually allowing people see your web page over the internet without using a web host that can be crawled by a search engine:

#### Firewall on your computer:

You would need to create a rule to allow inbound connections to your web server on the port it's hosted at.

- [Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/create-an-inbound-port-rule)
- [Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201642)

#### On your router:

This is the hardest part as there are many different routers and ways to go about this.

**Option 1:** Set up [port forwarding](https://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/) on your router. This is the safter way to go about this as it limits your computer's exposure to the internet.

**Option 2:** Put your computer in the [DMZ](https://routerguide.net/when-and-how-to-setup-dmz-host-for-home-use/). This is more dangerous as it exposes your computer to the internet.

#### Share your IP and port:

Once you've set up your firewall and router, you can share your [computer's internet IP](https://www.whatismyip.com/) and port number as a URL with the person you wish to see the page you are hosting IE `http://10.12.11.123:8080`.

If you have any with the firewall or router settings, I would suggest searching / asking on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: Thankyou very much sir @JoshZhang This is exactly what I asked. But there are some details I want to know on these: I don't have a routing device neither do I know how to use one, so my question is : Does the person (I am sharing this url with) need a router too or anything else to be able to open the page? For information, that person only has internet and will receive the URL I'll give. Any kind of complexity to that person in opening the page will lead to trouble.

Comment: Let's ignore the firewall and router for now. I'm now asking things which are related to this community. "allowing people see your web page over the internet without using a web host.." I can use a web host if it's free, first. Second, the first web page could be password protected so that when some foreign person if, opens my site shall not be able to see anything before entering the password (that I would create, I think this depends on how I design my web page, any software recommendation on this will be appreciated). Third, the domain or subdomain of URL should not contain the name..

Comment: ..of the software used. As you showed in the routing method, the URL should look like http://10.12.11.123:8080 or similar, but not like a third-party hosted website.

Comment: @AmanKushwaha the person you're sharing the URL will not need do anything but go to the URL you gave them. As for your second part of your question, if you wish to have a service host your web site but you only want an IP for the address instead of a name, you could use [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/host-static-website/) or [Azure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-html), the key part is to not use a [DNS](https://g.co/kgs/XFg5Gz).

Comment: Okay. I understand. If I don't use DNS, the URL will not have a domain name. These service AWS and Azure mention something called "static websites". I don't know what does that exactly mean but the website I'll host will take input from the user and the contents in the website should be able to change once published.

Comment: If your web site will have a database back end or use technology like PHP, you will need to use a different product. I believe they mean static as in you will be serving HTML web pages with no back end technology.

Comment: I tried Mongoose today and was able to share files on my computer but how can i share or create web pages with mongoose? Or any other software (you can recommend) to create a web page.

Comment: Mongoose only allows you to **host** web pages. To actually **create** pages, depends on what you're looking complexity wise. What is your experience level as far as creating web pages?

Comment: Not much complex, one input field, one enter button, the user should receive a message based on what was input. Experience level on creating web pages. Yes, if you consider html (read in school, till Linking web pages, formatting texts mostly, inserting images etc. but haven't learnt input field)

Comment: If it's very simple, web page I just doing it the manual way by typing out HTML code with an IDE of your choice like [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/). [W3Schools instructions on web forms](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).

Comment: Thank you again @JoshZhang. Let's say if I make one web page then how can I host it on internet using Mongoose? I couldn't find an option to do that. All I know about using mongoose is that it shares whatever file or folder I move to the C:/mongoose folder globally but I've no clue how to host a website.

Comment: In order to host over the internet, you would need to follow the firewall and router instructions I listed above.

Answer (score 1):

(low-tech solution)

Set your Apache server to serve HTTPS, then create two pages:

- `index.html` (empty)
- `3752837652938573294572309457238947532948057.html` (containing the information you want to make accessible to your friend)

By default Apache will not tell anyone about `3752837652938573294572309457238947532948057.html`. If you don't mention it anywhere on the web, search engines will not find it.

If you can send the URL to your friend in a secure way, they will be able to access the page, and thanks to HTTPS the page name [will not be sniffable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499591/are-https-urls-encrypted) by anyone.

I wrote `.html` but `.php` would work too.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for something like [Magic Wormhole](https://magic-wormhole.readthedocs.io/en/latest/welcome.html)?

Comment: Thank you for you response. Is it possible for you to share a sample webpage to me using that software?

Comment: @AmanKushwaha It is possible, yes.  Why do you want to do that?  If you just want to see how it works, why not try it yourself through two computers?

Comment: Good question. Answer: because I don't want to (neither have time to) try these many softwares, installing, doing all those things just to know that, this is not what I wanted! Also I want to ask if the other person is required to have magic wormhole software to be able to see my page? I don't have two computers. So I thought instead of asking so many queries I can ask directly to a person who is already using and handy with the software to share a URL saving the time for both of us.

Comment: I've edited my question. Please respond if possible. Any help will be appreciated.